# Stop visual studio from changing file encoding on save

Tags: visual-studio-2012, encoding, character-encoding

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web to edit some ANSI encoded html and javascript files. When I save the changes VS is changing the encoding of the files to UTF-8 with BOM.

Visual Studio issues the following warning:

`The character encoding for the file file.htm has changed. Your source control provider may have problems managing files with this type of encoding. For example, if you save an ANSI-encoded file as UTF-8 you may not be able to merge or show differences.`

Is there a way to make Visual Studio save files without changing encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML files, put the following `<meta>` tag between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
```

Next, save the files—Visual Studio will detect the `<meta>` tag and save the files in Windows-1252 (ANSI) encoding.

Comment: This actually occurs more widely than the original question implies.  That is to say, not only to html and javascript.  Is there a more basic way to change this behavior?  (I am having this issue in SSIS (XML under the hood)